# To install Chrome Extension locally

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to put Chrome Extension on my personal server and download and install it through a browser. However, if you receive and download crx as a response from the server, the error `crx_required_proof_missing` occurs. Is it impossible to put it on a personal server and proceed?

I created a crx file according to the document, uploaded it to the node server, received it from the browser, and proceeded with the download.

Comment: I think it is possible if you are a Linux user. [Installing extensions on Linux
](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/linux_hosting/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 75 has introduced some changes, where if an extension is downloaded using a direct URL, then it tries to be smart and figure its metadata which then contains the type which says that it's an extension and Chrome tries to install it immediately - which fails for custom extensions which are not in the Chrome Extension store.

So, if a CRX file is downloaded directly, Chrome figures out the file's `content-type` to be 'application/x-chrome-extension' which then triggers the auto-installation (and fails for custom extensions).

But if the same file is downloaded indirectly from a website, the website (in our case) sets the file's `content-type` to `application/octet-stream' which is a generic one and Chrome doesn't try to auto-install it.

So first make sure that the `content-type` with which your server offer the file is `application/x-chrome-extension`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm late in saying thank you. I tried it, but the error 'CRX_REQUIRED_PROF_MISSING' appears and cannot be installed. Maybe Chrome blocked the extension local installation for security reasons?